# How would I make something like a switch statement, but for multiple conditions

Tags: c#

```
private bool test(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int[] arr = {x,y,z};
    switch (arr)
    {
        case {4,5,6}:
            return true;
        case {1,2,3}:
            return true;
        case {7,8,9}:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want to create a function that does this. However, you cannot use an array value inside a switch statement.  How would I accomplish something like this? I don't really want to do a bunch of if statements, there will be around ~300 possible combinations.

For further clarification, the function will always return true if it finds a case, and returns false if it doesn't find a case. (Order matters)

One possible solution is I convert the x y z value to a string, of "x y z" then have a case of ~300 string values.  But that seems pretty hacky.

Comment: Why do you have 300 cases? What are the cases?

Comment: Are you trying to check if three numbers are consecutive?

Comment: @GiladGreen it takes in 3 indexers, which are indexers for some data.  Although this function does not have any form of access to that data.  The data is static.  I am writing a function called `test` to check if a data at the 3 index points exists.

Comment: @4D1C70 No, realistically it would be something like `case {29, 3 , 6} ` or something.  There will be around 300 cases.

Comment: What is the largest number you would see for x, y or z? Are you particularly worried about performance?

Comment: @DrewNoakes `index x`'s highest value is 50, `y` and `z` would be 6 as the highest value.  However, Gilad provided a solution that works well and looks very clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `HashSet` to facilitate the valid combinations. Then searching if a given `x,y,z` combination in it is done using `Contains` and as it is a HashSet takes `O(1)`:

```
HashSet<(int a, int b, int c)> options = new HashSet<(int a, int b, int c)>
{
    (4,5,6),
    (1,2,3),
    (7,8,9),
    // ... the rest of the cases
};

options.Contains((x, y, z));
```

For pre C# 7.0 use:

```
HashSet<Tuple<int, int, int>> options = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create(4,5,6),
    Tuple.Create(1,2,3),
};

options.Contains(Tuple.Create(x, y, z));
```

Do note that having 300 cases hard coded (or any number of cases hard coded) isn't a good practice. I suggest rethink how you store these values. You can store them in a database or configuration file and load them. Then after loading store in the `HashSet` as I suggested.

---

As for the `switch case` notice that if you have the same behavior for different cases you can:

```
switch (caseSwitch) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Order matters in a hashset correct? (4,5,6) != (5,4,6) as the three integers are indexers to data.

Comment: @asdsad - Order matters but not because of the `HashSet` (a hashset does not keep order) but because those are tuples. And each tuple has 3 properties.

Comment: Is there another way then to have a tuple? Seems as though `(int a, int b, int c)` is a C# 7.0 feature, I am on C# 4.0 (I am not able to update, as this is a massive project)

Answer (score 0):

Given the range on `x`, `y` and `z` is constrained to fit within a single byte each, you could pack all three into 24 bits of a 32-bit integer and reduce the memory footprint of your solution. Ints are value types (unlike `Tuple`) so won't require additional heap allocations in the structure, or during lookups.

```
internal sealed class MembershipSet
{
    private readonly HashSet<int> _members = new HashSet<int>();

    public void Add(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        _members.Add(Pack(x, y, z));
    }

    public bool Contains(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        return _members.Contains(Pack(x, y, z));
    }

    private static int Pack(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > 50)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(x));
        if (y < 0 || y > 6)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(y));
        if (z < 0 || z > 6)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(z));

        return x | y << 8 | z << 16;
    }
}
```